# How to install application on SDcard mounted on android emulator?

Tags: android, installation, adb

I am trying to install my own android application on SDcard using windows platform. First I set

`android:installLocation="preferExternal"`

in AndroidManifest.xml

Then I launched emulator through eclipse. While creating this AVD I had given SDcard size 500 MiB and had set the SDcard support property also in AVD Manager. But the error is

> [2011-03-22 05:01:31 - SDcardDemo]
>   Failed to install SDcardDemo.apk on
>   device 'emulator-5554! [2011-03-22
>   05:01:31 - SDcardDemo] (null)

I also tried to install using command line.

`D:\DATA\C\android-sdk_r06-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb install -avd test_AVD SDcardDemo.apk`

> 43 KB/s (14739 bytes in 0.328s) Error:
>   Unknown option: -a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb install -s [path to apk]` 
is the command which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

goto command prompt

and write

adb install filename.apk

Comment: I did that. But It gets located at /data/local/tmp which is phone's internal memory afaik. I want 2 install on SDcard. I have read that it is possible only on 2.2 android version. I am trying on same but not working. Or is there any way of moving it from phone mem to SDcard through emulator?