# How to install an application to SD card of the Android emulator rather than its internal memory?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can't find a way to install my app to SD card, nor move it post-installation through the emulator's Android settings UI. I do have `installLocation=auto` in the manifest, also tried `preferExternal`. Is this at all doable?

There's [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396499/how-to-install-application-on-sdcard-mounted-on-android-emulator), but the accepted answer no longer works:

```
adb install -s .\app-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install .\app-debug.apk:
Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: New installs into ASEC containers no longer supported
```

This is with Android 9 Google Services x86_64 image.

Comment: What is `.\\` in your path supposed to mean?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Current directory. That's how PowerShell auto-completes local relative paths. It's inconsequential and doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) you could use

```
set-install-location location
```

Where location is

> - 0: Auto: Let system decide the best location.
> - 1: Internal: install on    internal device storage.
> - 2: External: on external media.

Comment: Doesn't work:

```255|generic_x86_64:/ $ pm set-install-location 2

Security exception: Package android does not belong to 2000```

Comment: Please refer to the  answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917155/6156487 @VioletGiraffe

Comment: Interesting. That command succeeded (didn't know the emulator is rooted!), but the app is still being installed to internal memory by Android Studio.

Comment: The ADB APi was updated it is now:  "adb install --install-location 2 ..."

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it fails with this command if the application was not present on the device. The -s flag means reinstall as far as I remember so just omit this and simply do:
`adb install app.apk`